# Get Fed Tax Rate from Income Input Using Vlookup

Tags: vlookup

Been going crazy with this. I have income level and Filing Status as my inputs. I am trying to get the 2023 tax rate for the income within the tax Filing Status. I have tables that have the Filing status, lower limit, upper limit and tax rate for that income level. Since Vlookup needs a match in the first column, I cannot get anything but an #NA.

I must be missing something simple, but this is driving me crazy as this should be easy to accomplish in excel.

Thanks so much!

I have tried multiple layers of logic to no avail.

Comment: It will help if you can show how your lookup table is structured in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for response. I got it fixed. I was using TRUE at the end of the VLOOKUP incorrectly. Appreciate your response.